# JavaFX + Spring + JDBC is possible?

Tags: mysql, database, spring, jdbc, javafx

my school projekt task is to develop Issue tracking System. My imagine:

JavaFX desktop client application  +  Spring 4 server + MYSQL database

I would like to use JDBC to reach datas. How should I do it? Spring server made the queries and  after it, the spring server should send the client the serialized data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, though you don't need spring in that scenario.

Jdbc client would connect directly to the database over the network.

You would have to expose your database to public tcp connections, and firewalls would have to allow this too.

Other options:

1. Use a local database, like sqlite , and sync w central db over https using a tool like symmetricds. This gives you offline capabilty.
2. create a restful api on the server, and have the client get and set data using http.